# In Solaris server with Putty, unable to delete copied file with some irregular special character

Tags: solaris, delete-file

I use putty to log in to a solaris server. while i was performing a copy operation I pressed left arrow key to edit the file name but it kept adding this character **^[[D** desperate I pressed return key and the copy operation got complete

```
cp temp.jar temp.jar^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D
```

I was planning to rename is as temp.jar.test, I used 'ls' command to check what has happened and to my surprise two files came up with same name!

```
root[dev1]# ls -lt temp*
-rw-r--r--   1 root     other     488554 Apr 11 02:25 temp.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 root     other     488554 Apr 11 02:22 temp.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 root     other     488554 Apr 11 02:22 temp.jar.041114
-rw-r--r--   1 root     other     488487 Sep 30  2013 temp.jar.032514
```

and I used 'rm' command to delete, the original file got deleted but the file copied with ^[[D character is not getting deleted. And I'm getting a msg like 'eisvr.jar.: No such file or directory'

Help me delete the file. I tried issuing 'rm temp.jar^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D'. It resulted in more errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to run this command:

```
rm -i temp.jar?????????*
```

and answer yes when prompted to remove the bogus one.